# How can I attach a file name containing a / with sp_send_mail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping, dbmail

I have a query that sends an email to me each month for the previous month's data that we receive.  I'd like to include the last month and current year in the filename.  I got the month and year to work but when I try to show them in the filename, SQL tries to escape the line because I'm using a forward slash to separate month and year.

For example, the code below returns "2021.csv" as the filename.  How do I use a forward slash in the filename?

```
SELECT @query_attachment_filename = 
  N'SITLAMonthlyEntityReport'
 +N' '
 +CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) AS NVARCHAR(12))
 +N'/' -- This is the problem area.
 +CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4))
 +N'.csv';
```

I've tried using all of these methods without luck:

1. `N''/''` -- I get, "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for divide operator".
2. `''/''` -- I get, "Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator".
3. `['/']`
4. `/` -- I get, "Incorrect syntax near '/'".

I'd like to see this as an example filename: "SITLAMonthlyEntityReport 9/2021".

EDIT: I was asked for the entire query that included the snippet from above.  Below is the full query, minus email information.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @tab NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(9);
    DECLARE @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(520);
    DECLARE @CRLF NCHAR(2);

    SELECT @CRLF = NCHAR(13)+NCHAR(10)
    SELECT @subject = 'Well Information Report'
    SELECT @message = N'Dear ###, '
                      +@CRLF+ N''
                      +@CRLF+ N'Please refer to the attached spread sheet for the results of last month''s information report ('
                      +CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) AS NVARCHAR(12))
                      +N'/'
                      +CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4))
                      +N').'
                      +@CRLF+ N''
                      +@CRLF+ N'If there aren''t any results in the attached CSV, the query didn''t find any information for the last month,'
                      +@CRLF+ N''
                      +@CRLF+ N'Thanks,'
                      +@CRLF+ N'###';

    SELECT @query =
    '
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        --DECLARE @SearchYear AS NVARCHAR(4) = YEAR(GETDATE())
        --DECLARE @SearchMonth AS NVARCHAR(9) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
        DECLARE @SearchYear AS NVARCHAR(4) = 2021
        DECLARE @SearchMonth AS NVARCHAR(9) = 7

        SELECT
            API14,
            [Entity Number],
            [First Prod Date],
            [Spacing Rule],
            TPI AS [Top Producing Interval Location],
            BH AS [Bottom Hole Location],
            [Well History Comments],
            [Well History Modify Date] AS [Last Modified Date]
        FROM
        (
        SELECT
            dbo.BuildAPI14(Well.WellID, Construct.SideTrack, Construct.Completion) AS [API14],
            CAST(ConstructDate.EventDate AS DATE) AS [First Prod Date],
            Loc.LocType AS [Location Type],
            CONCAT(''Township '',LocExt.Township,LocExt.TownshipDir,'' '',''Range '',LocExt.Range,LocExt.RangeDir,'' Section '',LocExt.Sec,'' '',RefCounty.CountyName,'' County'') AS ''Location'',
            tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule AS [Spacing Rule],
            Lease.Number AS [Entity Number],
            WellHistory.WHComments AS [Well History Comments],
            WellHistory.ModifyDate AS [Well History Modify Date]
        FROM dbo.Well
            LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAPDTracker ON LEFT(tblAPDTracker.APINO,10) = Well.WellID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Construct ON Construct.WellKey = Well.PKey
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ConstructReservoir ON ConstructReservoir.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Lease ON Lease.Pkey = ConstructReservoir.LeaseKey
            LEFT JOIN dbo.WellHistory ON WellHistory.WellKey = Construct.WellKey
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ConstructDate ON ConstructDate.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND ConstructDate.Event = ''FirstProduction''
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Loc ON loc.ConstructKey = Construct.PKey AND Loc.LocType IN (''BH'',''TPI'')
            LEFT JOIN dbo.LocExt ON LocExt.LocKey = Loc.PKey
            LEFT JOIN dbo.RefCounty ON RefCounty.PKey = LocExt.County
        WHERE
                WellHistory.WorkType = ''ENTITY''
            AND WellHistory.ModifyUser = ''UTAH\###''
            AND YEAR(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchYear
            AND MONTH(WellHistory.ModifyDate) = @SearchMonth
        GROUP BY
            Well.WellID,
            Construct.SideTrack,
            Construct.Completion,
            ConstructDate.EventDate,
            Loc.LocType,
            LocExt.Township,
            LocExt.TownshipDir,
            LocExt.Range,
            LocExt.RangeDir,
            LocExt.Sec,
            RefCounty.CountyName,
            tblAPDTracker.SpacingRule,
            Lease.Number,
            WellHistory.WHComments,
            WellHistory.ModifyDate
        ) AS BasicQuery
        PIVOT
        (
        MIN(BasicQuery.Location) FOR [Location Type] IN ([TPI], [BH])
        ) AS PivotedQuery
        ORDER BY
            API14,
            [Well History Modify Date];
    '
    
    SELECT @query_attachment_filename = N'SITLAMonthlyEntityReport'
                                        +N' '
                                        +CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) AS NVARCHAR(12))
                                        +'/'
                                        +CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4))
                                        +N'.csv';

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = '###',
        @from_address = '###',
        @recipients = '###',
        @reply_to = '###',
        @body = @message,
        @query = @query,
        @query_attachment_filename = @query_attachment_filename,
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_result_header = 1,
        @query_result_width = 32767,
        @query_result_separator = @tab,
        @append_query_error = 0,
        @execute_query_database = 'UTRBDMSNET'
END
```

Comment: The error of a “invalid for divide operator” is not caused in that code. It would only result if the / **was not** in a string literal. There is no escaping problem here and literal / characters need bo escaping in strings.

Comment: @Larnu You want the whole query?

Comment: Yes, @Hiebs915 .

Comment: @Larnu Is it possible to include `/` in the filename?  If not, I'll use a period instead.

Comment: A *file's* name cannot have a `/` in  it, no @Hiebs915 . I recommend against `.` too though (that's normally to denote the extension). Use a hyphen perhaps.

Comment: (note: Any invalid character in a file name would be represented as a different error later. This is a SQL Server *parsing* error.)

Comment: The error is likely caused by a different version of code; or if this code was extracted from a string in a programming language, it is not the *actual command*; or it is preceded by invalid SQL..

Comment: @Larnu Ok. Thanks for the tip on using a period, didn't think of that in my last response to you.  I guess I might have to resort to using `-` instead.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm a little confused then.  When I use a `-` instead of a `/` the filename shows as "SITLAMonthlyEntityReport 9-2021".

Comment: I’m confused as well. What happens if using the expected literal directly?

Comment: The way that one would normally get such an error is, `select 'a' / 'b'` — this results in the error message shown, and it occurs because the / is outside a string.

Comment: @user2864740 If I use a `/` directly without single quotes around it I get, "Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: While invalid when executed (as the second arguments conversion to fails), the following parses correctly: `select 1 / 'foo/bar'`

Comment: A / *must* be quoted if it’s meant to be part of a string (because out of quotes it’s not a string..).. so again, back to some larger context.

Comment: @user2864740 If use `/` or `'/'` the filename is 2021.csv.  It only shows me the part after the escape.

Comment: That behavior **has nothing to do with the reported error**. And that seems logical.

Comment: So this entire run-around can be summarized as “how can I attach a file name containing a / with sp_send_mail”? And then all the *incorrect claims* can be omitted entirely.

Comment: The minimal SSCCE would be merely the sp_send_mail call with relevant literals used directly as arguments. None of the other code is relevant.

Comment: @user2864740 I was asked for more code so I added it.  All I wanted to do was use a `/` in an emailed filename from sp_send_mail.  Larnu said I couldn't so I figured it was over at that point.  I'll just a `-` instead.  If you want, you can suggest an edit to the title if you think it needs to be more clear.  I'd like my question to be clear and undertandable for others.

Comment: The run-about appears to occur at the “things tried” bit. These attempts include invalid syntax (not shown in the snippet above), eg. `select ''/''` is trivially invalid because it is the same as `select '' / ''`. Going back to a minimal SSCCE with literals (showing the given input and describing the behavior (that of the file name only including the last segment)) would avoid all of such, eg. `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail .. @query_attachment_filename = 'foo\bar.txt' ..` .. “attaches the filename as bar.txt”.

Comment: Then for any case with a syntax error (if relevant), show the full changes in the full (yet minimal SSCCE) context as a stand-alone query.